# what does the word CALL mean in call a routine/funtion?

Tags: function, subroutine

Let me give a simple sample code:

> a = b + c
>   print(a)

the 1st line says: ASSIGN the value of b + c to a

the 2nd line says: CALL the function print.
I don't really understand the world call here (not the 'technical' meaning to 'call' a function in C, etc).
It has the same meaning as in "call the police", "call Mr.Bean", etc
or it means to "visit", like to visit someone, etc?

Thanks

Comment: I always interpret it to be akin to `call on` or `ask`, as in _call on the function to do some work_, or _ask the function to do some work_.

Comment: Thanks! I think it is the transfer of control that it is called 'call', it is 'call on somebody to do something'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term was present in FORTRAN II in 1958. It doesn't seem to have come from the lambda calculus realm where one typically "applies" functions but I cannot find a definitive etymology. It might be findable in some of John Backus' writings. It might have come directly from one of the early instruction sets to implement some form of procedure linkage, but I don't think so.

From an English language perspective, we have "call a strike" where "call" means roughly the same things as "order," and "call upon" which means "to request from" or "to ask of."

Comment: Thanks! I think it is transfer of control that it is called 'call' - call on someone to do something, to ask. Hope I can find more explanation in some John Backus' writing or in some docs about Assembly Call instruction.